# sortBy function in React Virtualized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I am getting started on React Virtualized and while doing a table with sortable columns, I noticed that the documentation and examples are all including a "sortBy" function.
See documentation [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/d459cef40e774f611afeba1dad0e3fc1bfae6d66/source/Table/Table.example.js#L64-L72)

But I can't see that sortBy function being imported anywhere.

Is it expected that you make your own sortBy function or is React Virtualized coming with it and if so, how do I "import/activate" it?

For now I made it work with my own function but I am curious to know what is this "sortBy" function that is being referred to in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add sorting to table with react virtualized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591557/how-to-add-sorting-to-table-with-react-virtualized)

Comment: @Kobe - In this case I just want to find out what sortBy function the documentation is referring to. I don't need to know how to get React Virtualized to work as I am already done with the job I was doing.